# Antlr grammar and AST

Tags: antlr

```
grammar Poly;
options     
    {
    output=AST;
    ASTLabelType=CommonTree;
    }
poly
: 
     term(TLK^ term)*
;   
term 
: 
    a=ID b=INT -> ^($a $b)*
;
INT:'0'..'9';
ID:'a'..'z';
TLK:('PUSH'|'POP');
Semi : ';' {skip();};
Space  : ' ' {skip();};
```

This is my grammar file...my input is

```
PUSH t 6;POP t 7;PUSH t 8;
```

But it give the output as

```
(PUSH (POP (t 6) (t 7)) (t 8))
```

...And leaving a command as

> line 1:0 extraneous input 'PUSH' expecting ID

Why my first PUSH is not included in the tree?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you start in the `poly` rule, the first element on it's right side is `term`, which is an ID followed by INT, not `PUSH`:

```
poly
: 
     term(TLK^ term)*
;
```

To match the input you gave, you'll probably want this:

```
poly
: 
     (TLK^ term)*
;
```